# GMSMarker not show on button click run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3

I'm try to adding marker on run time then press button. Button method call and code run but no marker show on map. if i add marker on adding subview time then show perfectly but i need to different case on button press.

Button Click (Not Showing any maker on Map)

```
-(IBAction)addingMarkerOnMap:(id)sender
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
    GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    london.title = @"London";
    london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinIcon"];
    london.map = self.mapView;
 });
}
```

**Adding Time (Showing marker)**

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:16];

self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.frame camera:camera];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;    
[self.googleMapView addSubview:self.mapView];

self.marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.649580, -79.385440);
self.marker.title = @"Toronto";
self.marker.snippet = @"Canada";
self.marker.map = self.mapView;
```

Comment: What is googleMapView?  And why do you add a Google map view to it?

Comment: subView in ViewController.

Comment: like same as self.view

Comment: in viewdidload only you can add london marker but default it should be hidden when button press marker should be hidden no try this way

Comment: issue in after button press markers not showing

Comment: how to show marker ?

Comment: you tried in right way only.Can you declare it as global self. london = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
self london.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);

Comment: you have this name image in your project `"pinIcon"` ?

Comment: yes image "pinIcon" in project

Comment: @UmerAfzal after clicking on button, any other action performed like `[mapView clear]` or reload the mapview anything. it will also remove your pin.

Comment: how to reload mapview

Comment: i mean clear mapview and show again.

Comment: are you clear mapview after clicking on button ? if yes then don't do. It will remove your marker.

Comment: yes i already clear mapview then button press

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191208/discussion-between-nirav-kotecha-and-umer-afzal).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code on a demo project then check in your own project

```
@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
//use the following code in you button action
let state_marker = GMSMarker()
    let long = //Double long
    let lat = //Double lat
    state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)
    state_marker.map = mapView
     // add in subview if you want to add, or place a view on story board and assign GMSMapView to this
```

Comment: try it in swift for demo, might be you've issue in your code, i'm not good in Objective-C